# Using L-BFGS with regularization techniques such as dropout

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, optimization

I would like to train a small MLP on a small Dataset ~100K points.
I am attempting an optimization using full batch optimization using the L-BFGS solver.
The model overfits and therefore I would like to introduce some sort of regularization rather than early stopping on a validation set.

Could someone elaborate, if L-BFGS will work when using Dropout or layer normalization?